# react add many items in component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that accepts another component with 3 fields, and I want that I can add new entries to different fields

now I can add only the entry in firstname and I do not know how to make that for for the lastname and telegrams

if I just copy them, then the values are accepted only from one field

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            dataItems: []
        }
    }

addItem(value) {
    let newListItems = this.state.dataItems.slice();

    newListItems.push(value);
    this.setState({
        dataItems : newListItems
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.dataItems.map(function (item,index) {
                return (
                    <Hello key={index} firstname={item} lastname={item2} telegram={item3}/>
                );
            }, this)}

            <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    )
}
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div className='form__row'>
            <p className='form__input' > firstname: {this.props.firstname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> lastname: {this.props.lastname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> telegram: {this.props.telegram} </p>
        </div>;
    }
}

class AddItem extends React.Component{
    handleClick(){
        this.props.addItem(this.item.value);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='form__row'>
                <div>
                    <label >firstname</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item => this.item=item} />
                    <label >lastname</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item2 => this.item=item2} />
                    <label >telegram</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item3 => this.item=item3} />
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> add new in state</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: your addItem funciton param value is object or single value? If object then you pass this way `<Hello key={index} items={item}/>` then get it `this.props.items.firstname`

Comment: Please refer to the docs before you post a question. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question: you have two components: a form (`AddItem`) with three fields (`firstname`, `lastname` and `telegram`) and your entries from that form (`Hello`). And you want to keep adding the entries you put in through your form?

Comment: So say you put in something like: `John Smith 12345678`, is that what you want rendered? Then later you do, `John Smith 12345678` `Jane Doe 987654321`, they will be rendered as a list from your `Hello` component?

Comment: @theJuls yes,I want to fill in 3 fields and display them in hello component, when it displays in table component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple important things you got wrong. I'll break them down for you:

In your `AddItem` component, you are using an uncontrolled component, but overriding the same property `this.item` over and over again whenever setting the values for each form field. In this case, because it is the last one, `telegrams` value is the final one remaining. So it is the only one being set. It would be the same thing as trying to set three different value for the same variable.

```
item.value = 1
item.value = 2
item.value = 3
```

If you used this code snippet, obviously the only value of item will be `3`. So we first fix this component by associating different properties to each form:

```
// AddItem component's render function
render(){
    return (
        <div className='form__row'>
            <div>
                <label >firstname</label>
                <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item => this.item=item} />
                <label >lastname</label>
                <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item2 => this.item2=item2} />
                <label >telegram</label>
                <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item3 => this.item3=item3} />
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> add new in state</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

On another note, I highly recommend actually giving your three items meaningful names. So I would switch them to `firstName`, `lastName` and `telegram` specifically.

Your `handleClick` also suffers from the same problem: You were passing the same this.item.value, meaning you were just passing your last set field. For you to pass all three of them while keeping the function in it's same format, you need to create an object with all three of your `item.value`. With that change, it should now look like this:

```
handleClick(){
  const value = {item: this.item.value, item2: this.item2.value, item3: this.item3.value}
  this.props.addItem(value);
}
```

Finally, in your `Table` component, some changes are needed in its render function. It looks like you are confusing the `item` you named in your map function with `item` you passed in. Again, you should probably find a more meaningly names for your variables so that doesn't happen.

The `item` in the map function, is each item of the array you are mapping through. In this case, it would be just the object with all three of your fields. You actually want the `item` fields from the `item` of the map function.

```
       {this.state.dataItems.map(function (item,index) {
            return (
                <Hello key={index} firstname={item.item} lastname={item.item2} telegram={item.item3}/>
            );
        }, this)}
```

Here is a working version of your app:

```js
class Table extends React.Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      dataItems: []
    }
    
  }
  
  addItem(value) {
    
    let newListItems = this.state.dataItems.slice();
    console.warn(newListItems)

    newListItems.push(value);
    this.setState({
        dataItems : newListItems
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.dataItems.map(function (item,index) {
          return (
            <Hello key={index} firstname={item.item} lastname={item.item2} telegram={item.item3}/>
          );
        }, this)}

        <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  } 
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div className='form__row'>
            <p className='form__input' > firstname: {this.props.firstname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> lastname: {this.props.lastname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> telegram: {this.props.telegram} </p>
        </div>;
    }
}

class AddItem extends React.Component{
    handleClick(){
      const value = {item: this.item.value, item2: this.item2.value, item3: this.item3.value}
      this.props.addItem(value);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='form__row'>
                <div>
                    <label >firstname</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item => this.item=item} />
                    <label >lastname</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item2 => this.item2=item2} />
                    <label >telegram</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item3 => this.item3=item3} />
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> add new in state</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Table />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```